# How to Move Photos out of an Event and into the Main section of iphoto?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, photos.app

I have created many events over the years of having my mac... and I am noticing that my events are becoming very jumbled from importing photos over the years and just tossing them into the closest relative event I can find.. I am wanting to have all my photos in the basic part of iphoto without any events.. so that I can recreate ALBUMS that appropriately file my pictures so I can find them easily when I need them.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[Events](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2361) are an integral part of iPhoto.

You *can't* have no events. However, you can ignore them. Just select 'Photos' on the left side list:

[image]

(iPhoto remembers your selection and will display the 'Photos' view next time you start it) and configure the time frame iPhoto should use to autosplit photos into events (I use an 8-hour gap):

[image]

iPhoto won't bother you about creating new events.

Now you can group your pictures in albums: in the 'Photos' view, select the photos you want to include in an album and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. A new, unnamed album that contains the previously selected photos will appear in the Albums list. Rename it and you're done.

Note that iPhoto won't automatically add imported photos to your albums. If you want your albums to be updated based on certain criteria use [smart albums](http://help.apple.com/iphoto/index.html#pht6d60ca71) instead.